# Linq : Object property based on other properties of same object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, oop

Today i am stuck with object property value selection based on other property value of the same object. following is my class structure and i have converted class to object from XML using Serializer and i want to select "Mainsnow" List based on value of "Name" in "City" class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Mainsnow")]
public class Mainsnow
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MainsnowCode")]
    public string MainsnowCode { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "City")]
public class City
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mainsnow")]
    public List<Mainsnow> Mainsnow { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Mainsnows")]
public class Mainsnows
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
    public City City { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MainsnowData")]
public class MainsnowData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mainsnows")]
    public Mainsnows Mainsnows { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried various expect like below but nothing works for me can any buddy help please.

```
MainsnowData.Mainsnows.City.Name.Select(t => t.ToString() == "test")
```

In above aspect i want to access "Mainsnow" for related "Name" of "City" class.

Thanks

Comment: Vary confusing class and property names, but I assume you want `List<Mainsnow> data = MainsnowData.Mainsnows.City.Where(x => x.Name == "test").Mainsnow;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke based on the classes `City` is not a collection

Answer (score 0):

The Assumption here would be that you are trying to get the data out of a collection of `MainsnowData` that was loaded from a data source

```
List<MainsnowData> items = LoadDataFromXml();
```

You would then you Linq to project the desired output

```
Mainsnow[] mainsnows = items.Where(m => m.Mainsnows.City.Name == "test")
                            .SelectMany(m => m.Mainsnows.City.Mainsnow)
                            .ToArray();
```